# Gitlab-ci.yml file in Android Studio not retrieving user Predefined variables saved in the CI/CD Variables settings?

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I haven't found anything useful online, I am also fairly new to the Gitlab pipeline.

Here is what I have:

```
cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" 
  paths:
    - .gradle/

image: xxx_irrelevant

before_script:
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - export SSL_CERT_DIR="/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs"
  - make ui-tests-clean

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - scan

xxx_scan:
  stage: scan
  before_script:
    - echo "running xxx scan"
  image: some_image_not_relevant
  tags:
    - nite
  variables:
    APIKEY: $APIKEY
    USERKEY: $USERKEY
    WSS_URL: "xxx_some_url_not_relevant"
    PRODUCTNAME: $PRODUCT_TOKEN
    PROJECTNAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  script: not_relevant_this_is_working
  only:
    - main
```

but on Gitlab I have those variables defined, and I know it's not retrieving them because when I hardcode in the APIKEY, the security scan works. But when I have what I have below, it says "Bad Org Token" which means its not able to get the APIKEY. Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of Gitlab Variables Settings]

Answer (score 0):

omg, I feel so silly. The Gitlab documentation says that Protected variables will only be available on Protected branches.... The branch I was on was not protected, it was a random branch I had. The solution was to make the variables unprotected.